# Deploy WP8 app to device and save all its settings after rebuilding the project

Tags: windows-phone-8, device, isolatedstorage, rebuild, isolatedstoragefile

I have accidentally killed one of my WP projects in VS2013. I receovered the source code from the backup, but now, if I try to recompile it and deploy to my device for further debugging, all my app data in the app IsolatedStodage area will be wiped (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362744/all-files-in-isolatedstoragefile-store-disappear-after-rebuilding-wp8-silverligh)).

The problem is that I have gathered some important data in my app, and need to save them for later use with newer versions of my app. Is there a way to access the file system on a WP device unlocked for development and save the corresponding IsolatedStorage files for the app? I know that it's possible for the WP8/8.1 emulator (we can mount the .vhd files), but what about a WP device? And if it it's possible, what files/folders do we need to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/).

It allows you to browse the IsolatedStorage of application on both emulator and device. You need to copy all the files from IsolatedStorage and upload them to device after updating the application.

Comment: I cannot express my gratitude for telling me about this tool using any existing words!